# Algorithm for sorting elements in array by value

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I'm having trouble coming up with an algorithm to sort three random values that are being placed into an array.

```
int[] sortArray = anArray;

if (anArray[0] >= anArray[1]){
        sortArray[1] = anArray[0];
        sortArray[0] = anArray[1];
    } else if (sortArray[1] >= anArray[2]){
        sortArray[2] = sortArray[1];
        sortArray[1] = anArray[2];
    } else if (sortArray[0] >= sortArray[1]){
        sortArray[1] = anArray[0];      
    } else if (sortArray[0] >= sortArray[2]){
        sortArray[2] = anArray[0];
    } else {
    }
```

This is what I have been fooling around with for a while and I can't get it to work in every random generation of numbers.

Output

```
The original array:
Entry 0 is 9
Entry 1 is 5
Entry 2 is 0

The sorted array: 
Element 0 is 9
Element 1 is 9
Element 2 is 0
```

Any working algorithms, pseudo code or not, would be appreciated

Comment: Use Loop and sort them.

Comment: Is this an assignment?  If not, just use [Arrays.sort(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28int[]%29).

Comment: Whats wrong with sorting normally? `anArray.sort(comparator)`?

Comment: Arry sort http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_sort_int.htm

Comment: Due to your else-if structure you set at most 2 values in `sortArray`. How is that ever supposed to work?

Comment: One plan: (1) Copy every element from `anArray` to `sortedArray` (2) Find the smallest one, and if it isn't `sortedArray[0]`, swap it with `sortedArray[0]` (3) Swap the last two elements if necessary.

Comment: @ajb I had that in my code but forgot to paste it into the question.
VincentvanderWeele See above response

Comment: @ThomasJazz **What you did will not work**!  If you were trying to copy `anArray` to `sortedArray`, you didn't do that.  What you did is to make `anArray` and `sortedArray` be a reference to the same array object.  That means that if you change `sortedArray`, you're also changing `anArray`.  I doubt that's what you want.  Either copy each element one by one, using a loop, or use [`Arrays.copyOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf-int:A-int-) to initialize `sortedArray`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way:

```
Arrays.sort(anArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

first understand that only one if condition will satisfy among written by you.

Problem in your code  :
If I take your data set then it will be the first one. 
In that block you are assigning only two values in place of all three values .
Solution :
Use either nested if checks or AND/OR conditions to know the order of the values .
And change code to assign all three values in one block.

Example

```
if (anArray[0] >= anArray[1]  ){
    if(anArray[0] >= anArray[2]){
        // found max value  anArray[0]
        sortArray[0] = anArray[0];
        // find the max of remaining values by using anArray[2] > anArray[1]
        // set the 2nd and 3rd value 
        if(anArray[2] > anArray[1]){
            sortArray[1] = anArray[2];
            sortArray[2] = anArray[1];
        }else{
            sortArray[1] = anArray[1];
            sortArray[2] = anArray[2];
        }
    }else{
        // found max value in  anArray[2]
        sortArray[0] = anArray[2];
        // array[0] is greater than array[1] in top if .So we know order of anArray[0] and anArray[1]
        sortArray[1] = anArray[0];
        sortArray[2] = anArray[1];
    }

} else{
    if(anArray[1] >= anArray[2]){
        // found max value  as anArray[1] 
        sortArray[0] = anArray[1];
        // finding order between  anArray[0] and  anArray[2]
        if(anArray[0] >= anArray[2]){
            sortArray[1] = anArray[0];
            sortArray[2] = anArray[2];
        }else{
            sortArray[1] = anArray[2];
            sortArray[2] = anArray[0];
        }
    }else{
        //found max value as anArray[2]
        sortArray[0] = anArray[2];
        // the order between anArray[1] and anArray[0] we already know
        sortArray[1] = anArray[1];
        sortArray[2] = anArray[0];
    }
}
```

Above Solution was using if nesting .

Using AND/OR you can do this as follows -

```
if (anArray[0] >= anArray[1] && anArray[0] >= anArray[2] && anArray[2] >= anArray[1] ){
    sortArray[0] = anArray[0];
    sortArray[1] = anArray[2];
    sortArray[2] = anArray[1];
}else if (anArray[0] >= anArray[1] && anArray[2] >= anArray[0] ){
    sortArray[0] = anArray[0];
    sortArray[1] = anArray[1];
    sortArray[2] = anArray[2];
}else if (anArray[1] >= anArray[0] &&  anArray[1] >= anArray[2] && anArray[0] >= anArray[2]  ){
    sortArray[0] = anArray[1];
    sortArray[1] = anArray[0];
    sortArray[2] = anArray[2];
}else if (anArray[1] >= anArray[0] &&  anArray[2] >= anArray[1] ){
    sortArray[0] = anArray[2];
    sortArray[1] = anArray[1];
    sortArray[2] = anArray[0];
}
```

It is quite obvious that above code can be buggy and is not recommended.
Best option is to  use

```
Arrays.sort(anArray)
```

from collections api .